# How to find compiled function source code in R package?

Tags: r

For example, I am looking into a `R` function `PTdensity.R` source code in a package called `DPpackage`, where I found the author called a `fortran` function `ptdensityu` :

```
 foo <- .Fortran("ptdensityu", ...
```

The thing is how to find source code for `ptdensityu` subroutine. It may contains in a certain fortran file in `/src/` directory, but how do I know which file is it. (Actually I found it by manually check each file under `/src/` and found it is in the `/src/PTudensity.f`.)

Quick link for the package : [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/index.html)

PS: I used to use this [link](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp:8080/source/search?q=loglik_unippt&project=R&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=) to search source code, but somehow it does not work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a linux box, you use the `grep` command. In emacs, you build a tags file. In other editors there's probably similar functions. In Windows, can't you right click on a folder, hit Search... and fill in the 'A word or phrase in the file" box. Or install cygwin and use the `grep` command.

Amazes me that people are using computers without basic skills such as finding a string in a file...

Comment: Thank you. It is quite easy, powerful and useful with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you untarred [this](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/DPpackage_1.1-6.tar.gz)...............?

(It was the first subroutine in PTudensity.f)

Comment: Yes, I untared it. But the thing is how can you know it's in that file. There might be hundreds of fortran files in `/src` .

Comment: I saw the PTudensity.f file in the directory and opened it in a text editor. There it was. It didn't seem that difficult. For more deeply buried items you should be able to use whatever operating system utilities you like to search within the /src/ directory. Spacedman gives you Linux and Windoze examples. On a Mac I suspect that the Finder search facility uses rep "under the hood".

Comment: Thanks. I am trying that. I just blamed myself how I missed the basic idea of 'finding' something. Thanks for the idea.